# how to find the "::get" in php or its framwork?

Tags: php, laravel, thinkphp

I can not understand the `::get` in `thinkphp` and `laravel` ,I can find the `Session::get` or the `self::get`  .So Is the `::get` is the function? I use the `phpstorm` but I can not find the definition of that . it is the meaning of "`::get`" but not the symbol of "`::`"

Comment: Can you show an example of where it is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to educate yourself on Laravel's use of [Facades](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/facades) when you call Session::get(), by default you Laravel will actually give you an instance of the [Illuminate\Session\Store::class](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Session/Store.html) which is where you will find the ::get() method you are looking for.

When using PHPStorm it is only going to take you the Facade, not the concrete implementation that you are actually working with.

This is very common in Laravel, it'll take a bit of time for you to figure out which classes your actually working with, but diving into the framework will help you understand these things.

The Self::get() you are referring to looks to be Model class, which inherits the [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html)

Comment: I think the point of confusion in the question as written (and comments) is not knowing what static methods are and how to call them; if you answer the question this should be addressed.

Comment: I'd beg to differ, he's using PHPStorm and he's trying to click through the Session::get() to get it's implementation but it's only taking him the the Facade class which never mentions the actual class that Laravel instantiates during runtime.

Comment: There is for sure a Laravel element here but see for example [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68158244/how-to-find-the-get-in-php-or-its-framwork/68158585?noredirect=1#comment120462289_68158325). If unclear, I’m suggesting you address this simply by pointing to any reference about static php methods in the answer.